# Reference type of JVM

Tags: java, jvm

In some Java literature, The statement

> The reference type of the Java virtual
>   machine is **cleverly** named
>   reference

is widely popular. However, authors tend not to explain more why such statement is valid. Another thing that would make me understand this more is

> What does the reference type of the JVM means ? Does the JVM represent itself in the heap ?

Would appreciate a lot an explanation on this statement.

Thank you,

Ashmawy

Answer (score 10):

The word you're looking for here is [irony](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/irony):

> the use of words to convey a meaning that is the opposite of its literal meaning

The use of "clever" in that sentence is clearly ironic.  *"The reference type of the Java virtual machine is given the clearly **really stupidly obvious** name 'reference'"* is another way to read that sentence.

Answer (score 5):

I think the `cleverly` part relates to the fact that a reference type is typically called a `pointer`, which necessitates the reader to learn two terms. The JVM terminology simply uses the term `reference` for this.

There's also a historical context.

When Java was introduced, its biggest competitor was C++. C++'s main problem was that it was deemed to be too difficult. Java initially positioned itself as the *easy alternative* to C++. It had a syntax very close to C++, but all the difficult stuff (operator overloading, templates, multiple pass-by mechanisms) etc were removed from the language.

And now comes the catch...

Java was initially marketed as **not having pointers**. The rationale for saying this was that pointers were deemed the most difficult thing of C++, so if Java would not have them, it had to be a simpler language.

The *clever* part thus comes from simply inventing another term for 'pointer'. Call them reference and you can state Java does not have pointers (but references).

This has lead to many debates and caused a good amount of confusion, especially since C++ already had the term 'reference' and uses it for something else (though conceptually a little related). The debate usually centers around two camps where one of them claims Java indeed does not have pointers, since you can't do pointer arithmetic with them and they don't directly represent memory addresses, while the other camp states that you don't have to be able to do arithmetic with a pointer to call it a pointer.

Put differently, whether it was *clever* to use the term `reference` is still open for debate.

Comment: References are typically called pointers only in languages (hello C!) that don't distinguish between the two.  References are usually *implemented* as pointers, yes, but they're not usually *called* pointers unless you're in an anaemic language that lacks the ability to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

This becomes clearer when the whole paragraph is taken into context:

> The reference type of the Java virtual machine is cleverly named reference. Values of type reference come in three flavors: the class type, the interface type, and the array type. All three types have values that are references to dynamically created objects. The class type's values are references to class instances. The array type's values are references to arrays, which are full-fledged objects in the Java virtual machine. The interface type's values are references to class instances that implement an interface. One other reference value is the null value, which indicates the reference variable doesn't refer to any object.

(Taken from http://javadeveloper-jayaprakash-m.blogspot.com/)

I would assume from this that the "cleverly named" bit is referring to the fact that the references come in three different types and the JVM can distinguish between each one.

Comment: Well, Yeah the generalization of the following subcategorized reference types (Class,Interface,Array) is simply obvious. But using the word _clever_ in that statement automatically trigger an assumption that an underlying more subtle (not that obvious) reason that the JVM reference is named reference.

Comment: Since its not named pointer. But that is what it is. That would not be clever, since the connection to the C language would have been made clear.

Answer (score -1):

Or maybe it is only notion to express different approach taken by JVM designers for memory management.

If you'll remember in C/C++ one have freedom to allocate memory for variable either in local stack or in global heap. It is possible in C++ to allocate memory for object in method's local stack and then pass entire object as a parameter to other methods.

Java designers took away this freedom from developers. You just cannot create objects in local stack, only in global heap. So every variable of type Class/Interface/Array is indeed a reference to some memory address in the heap.  And you cannot pass object by value only by reference.

If you don't have a choice - than you don't even need to think about what type of variable you have - value type or reference type.

Comment: If you don't think about whether you're dealing with a value or reference type in Java, please don't ever let your Java code be used for anything people count on.